# Why are invisible elements of my buttons displaced in my responsive design?

Tags: android, html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I am working with my responsive design for the following site:

The problem occurs when I click the Artwork button while in mobile view. When I click the artwork button a second menu (made up of images) appears underneath the first one. This second menu if examined using google chrome developer tools shows that some invisible elements for the second menu are positioned over the first set of buttons causing a conflict. I would like to know how I can correct this conflict using my css. I believe the culprit is the #nowrap li element but I dont know how to correct this in CSS. From what I can see using developer tools the #nowrap li element is displaced from its image link. I have tried to adjust #nowrap li and have had no luck. I have included the HTML and CSS code below:

```css
#navbar {
  margin-top: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  height: 280px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#navbar li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
}

#navbar li a {
  padding: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 90px;
  margin-top: 150px;
  border: 4px solid #000;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#navbar li a:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: #eee;
}

#logo {
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
  margin-top: -60px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 85px;
  max-width: 100%;
  right: 0px;
}

.graphic {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
}

#nowrap,
li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

#A {
  position: relative;
  right: 0%;
}

#B {
  position: relative;
  right: 5%:
}

#C {
  position: relative;
  right: -10%;
}

#D {
  position: relative;
  right: -15%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  #navbar li {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  #logo {
    position: relative;
    top: -900px;
    right: 70px;
  }
  #whiteFile {
    height: 70px;
    top: 130px;
  }
  #nowrap li {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  #navbar li a {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  #A,
  #B,
  #C,
  #D {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top: 565px;
    right: 0px;
  }
  #item {
    top: 565px;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="nowrap">
  <li><img id="A" src="GRAPHICSw.png" height="95" width="290"></li>
  <li>
    <a href="VIDEOS.html#item"><img id="B" src="VIDEOSb.png" height="95" width="290"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="PHOTOS.html#item"><img id="C" src="PHOTOSb.png" height="95" width="290"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="WEBSITES.html#item"><img id="D" src="WEBSITESb.png" height="95" width="290"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="whiteFile"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was an easy fix. My CSS was treating the individual images of my menu separating them from the ul. I needed to zero out the images placement and adjust the ul instead of the images.